# glReadPixels gives a black image only on iOS 7 device

Tags: iphone, ios7, opengl-es, glreadpixels

In an OpenGL ES app I'm working on, I noticed that the `glReadPixels()` function fails to work across all devices/simulators. To test this, I created a bare-bones sample OpenGL app. I set the background color on an EAGLContext context and tried to read the pixels using `glReadPixels()` as follows:

```
int bytesPerPixel = 4;
int bufferSize = _backingWidth * _backingHeight * bytesPerPixel;

void* pixelBuffer = malloc(bufferSize);
glReadPixels(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

// pixelBuffer should now have meaningful color/pixel data, but it's null for iOS 7 devices

free(pixelBuffer);
```

This works as expected on the simulator for iOS 6 and 7 and a physical iOS 6 device, but it fails on a physical iOS 7 device. The scenarios tested are shown in the table below (YES/NO = works/doesn't):

[image: Test]

I'm using OpenGL ES v1.1 (though v2 also fails to work after a quick test).

Has anyone encountered this problem? Am I missing something? The strangest part of this is that it only fails on iOS 7 physical devices.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/sagarjp/9539678) is a gist with all the relevant code and the bare-bones [GitHub project](https://github.com/allewun/OpenGLESDemo/tree/master) for reference. I've made it very easy to build and demonstrate the issue.

***UPDATE***:

Here is the [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/sagarjp/9560241), and the [GitHub project](https://github.com/allewun/OpenGLESDemo/tree/master) has been updated too. I've updated the sample project so that you can easily view the memory output from `glReadPixels`.

Also, I have a new observation: When the `EAGLContext` is layer-backed (`[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer]`), `glReadPixels` can successfully read data on all devices/simulators (iOS 6 and 7). However, when you toggle the flag in GLView.m so that the context is not layer-backed (`[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:nil]`), `glReadPixels` exhibits the condition expressed in the initial post (works on iOS 6 sim/device, iOS 7 sim, but fails on iOS 7 device).

Comment: Do you have the right context at this time, or could there be a chance you are calling a clear before this ?

Comment: I have copied your code and it works. You need to call the read pixels method before you present the buffer.

Comment: @prabindh I haven't called clear before this.

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks! So should I call the captureFrame before glRenderbufferStorageOES or presentRenderbuffer?

Comment: I tried calling `[self captureFrame]` before `presentRenderBuffer` but I still get null bytes in buffer. Just to confirm, did you try it on iOS 7 device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the comments I managed to use your code and it worked. However, I defined your `BACKING_TYPE_LAYERBACKED` which generates the render buffer from the view.

The other pipeline that creates the FBO did not work though. The issue in your FBO pipeline is calling `[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:nil]`. Remove this line and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why that line worked differently in iOS 6 compared to iOS 7? Was the iOS 6 implementation wrong?

Comment: I have no idea, there are no docs about passing a nil parameter. All that says is "the value of this parameter must be a CAEAGLLayer object". Anyway there is no sense in calling it, on iOS 6 it seems to do nothing while on iOS 7 it definitely does something evil :)

Answer (score 0):

To continue from Matic Oblak's answer, for those who might encounter this issue when using a second back buffer( data backed - storage not from layer ) for tasks like [object](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/) [picking](https://github.com/andersonfreitas/opengl-tutorial-org/blob/19101e8eeb553602ad0ed03594491b8aa5265ff1/misc05_picking/misc05_picking_slow_easy.cpp), on device, you will need to rebind frameBuffer, renderBuffer and then **re-attach renderBuffer to frameBuffer**. For e.g the `bindBuffers` function in [gist](https://gist.github.com/sagarjp/9560241) would be as below

```
- (void)bindBuffers
{
  glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, _framebuffer);
  glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _renderbuffer);
  glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _renderbuffer);
}
```